# SendSettingsToPgf fails with pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23. Is there a quick work-around?

Tags: tikz-pgf, siunitx

I just installed Texlive2021 for Windows and `\SendSettingToPgf` fails.  The same code works in Overleaf.

Is there a quick work-aroud?  Alternatively, are there step-by-step instructions to install the 2020 version.  I am not sure what to download and how to point it to Texlive2020.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf,siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}
,separate-uncertainty}
\SendSettingsToPgf
```

Here is the logfile:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./untitled-2.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-06-18>
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex)
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.cod
e.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.c
ode.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex)

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex)))
 (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.st
y)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.st
y)) (c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/siunitx/siunitx.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/translations/translations.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)))
(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 \SendSettingsToPgf
                      
?
```

Comment: until you update your document you can use the old version of `siunitx` by using `\usepackage{pgf}\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]`

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten about that command - I'll look at adding some emulation.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\usepackage{siunitx}[=v2]` and `\usepackage{siunitx}[=2020-02-25]` both still fails with the same error?  Seems the option is ignored?

Comment: https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/501

Comment: @skvery it worked when I tried it, make sure something hasn't already loaded v3

Comment: @DavidCarlisle you were correct, had a duplicate.  Now it runs but the Beamer sans-serif fonts are missing from circuitikz pictures, it uses a Roman font for units.

Comment: Hmm can you try to have a minimal example? FWIK `circuitikz` does not plays with fonts, so should be beamer...